# I am trying to create a web app using Access 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, app

Hi I am trying to create a web app using Access 2013 I am getting the following errors

> There was a problem accessing the app's database.
>
> Details: Unable to obtain master key
>
> Apps are disabled on this site.
>
> Details: Apps cannot be installed. Review the diagnostic logs for more
>   details regarding app deployment failures

[image: error screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like while provisioning Access DB it's failing. Most likely below option is causing an issue from SQL Side.

**Enable Contained Databases** In SQL Server Management Studio, right-click the server node and choose properties. On the General page, there is a property, “Enable Contained Databases”, that you switch to True. Restart SQL Service Post making changes.

**Setting SQL Security** Mode We also need to set the SQL Security mode to “SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode”. In SQL Server Management Studio, right-click the server node and choose Properties. Choose the Security page and choose the “SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode” option. Restart SQL Service Post making changes.